# Dynamic images in LMS reports

Tags: birt, lms

I work on LMS reports in Plateau Report Designer, and for a recent report I have to include one of three embedded images dynamically - in accordance to a value that I get in a certain column. Is this doable at all? I can influence images in the master page, but that is done once per run, not per record. These images need to be embedded with the data.

One possible way would be to include them all in a cell and then to delete those that I don't need, but I don't know how to do that.
Another theoretic way would be to create a computer column, but I don't now how to include an image.

I tried to find something on the net, but there is virtually no documentation on this topic. Help!

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the image file name in your data set or in the binding of the surrounnding list/table item, then you can use the "image from shared resource" like this:

[image: Image Item Editor screenshot]

In this example, the column LOGO_DATEI contains the image file name.
The file path is relative to the folder specified in Window / Preferences / Report Design / Resource / Resource folder.

Comment: When the report is run from PRD, this is a possible solution. My reports get uploaded to an LMS server, where I unfortunately can't use shared resources.

Comment: Then you could embed all three images into the report (see "Embedded image" in the screenshot) and use a "visiblitiy expression" for each of them in such a way that at most one of the images is displayed. The visibility expression is Javascript syntax.